# Matrix norm properties: inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Is the fololwing relationship always true:
$x^{\top} (A - \frac{1}{2} \|A\|_F \, I_3) x > 0$, knowing that matrix A is definite positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $x^T=(1,0,0)$ and $A=\operatorname{diag}(\varepsilon,1,1)$, where $\varepsilon>0$ is small.